Jittery BLDC motor using Arduino and L6234 driver
I'm trying to spin a BLDC motor using the ESP32-based Arduino Nano 33 BLE and the STM L6234 BLDC motor driver. I have written code in MicroPython to drive the motor, but unfortunately the motor keeps jittering.
Here is an overview of the code:
from machine import Pin, PWM
import math
import time

# 1. Set frequency and resolution
frequency_pwm = 50_000 # 50 kHz (operating frequency of L6234)
resolution_bit = 12
resolution_int = (2 ** resolution_bit) - 1 

# 2. Pull ENABLE pins on L6234 high
ena_pins = [Pin(17), Pin(18), Pin(21)]
for ena in ena_pins:
  ena.value(1)

# 3. Set PWM pins on Arduino Nano 33
pwm_pins = [Pin(8), Pin(9), Pin(10)]
pwms = [PWM(pin) for pin in pwm_pins]
for pwm in pwms:
    pwm.freq(frequency_pwm)

# 4. Generate a sine wave
table_size = 360
sine_table = [(math.sin(math.radians(z)) + 1) / 2 * resolution_int for z in range(table_size + 1)]

def update_pwm(angle):

    # 6. Get three-phase indices
    index_a = angle % table_size
    index_b = (angle + 120) % table_size
    index_c = (angle + 240) % table_size

    # 7. Get PWM value from sine table
    duty_a = int(sine_table[index_a])
    duty_b = int(sine_table[index_b])
    duty_c = int(sine_table[index_c])

    # 8. Set pwm duty cycle
    pwms[0].duty_u16(duty_a) # Use duty_u16 for resolutions > 10 bit
    pwms[1].duty_u16(duty_b)
    pwms[2].duty_u16(duty_c)

def main():
    # 5. Increment angles
    angle = 0
    steps = 1
    while True:
        update_pwm(angle)
        angle += steps

main()


I'm assuming when you say "jitter", you're referring to phase loss in the motor? If you have the correct code, has there been any troubleshooting on the hardware side?
